# Optimize a function over a set of values

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python, and I'm trying to minimize a function over a given dataset. That is, I have a set of values for a vector x, and I'm trying to minimize a function f(x) for x in my data.

For clarity, I have data `X=np.array([[1,-1], [2,2], [-1,0]])` and I want to minimize a function `f(x) = x[0] + x[1]`, such that it returns a functional value `-1` for `x = [-1,0]`.

In actuality my dataset is much larger, so I'd rather not create an array of functional values and minimize that with `min()`, if it can be avoided.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Comment: I know how to minimize functions in general, and that doesn't tell me how to do it over a set.